# How to find if an r-value reference is a result of an explicit application of std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to implement a container which (for some reason) does not allow to implement a simple "reference type". It is something similar to `vector<bool>`, where the reference is actually a small object representing a "reference" to a particular element of the container.

Now I would like to use "modifying" STL algorithms like `std::sort` for this container and make it as efficient as possible. Everything works quite fine as soon as the algorithm is based simply on swaps and comparisons of the reference objects since both can be done fast even for heavy objects stored in the container.

The problem comes when the algorithm is trying to make a copy to a temporary value like, e.g., in some implementations of the insertion sort where at some point the code contains the statement

```
value_type val = * iterator;
```

where `* iterator` (the custom `operator*()`) returns a light-weight reference object *by value*. I could implement a move constructor (as well as the assignment) from reference r-value to the value type and implement it efficiently, but this would effectively "steal" the content of the value the iterator "points" to which is not at all the intention of the above statement. What would be nice if there was a way how to distinguish between this kind of statement and

```
value_type val = std::move(* iterator)
```

where I could steal the content of the "reference" without remorse.

I thought about adding a "flag" to the reference object to denote whether or not it is safe to make a move or make a copy instead from the given reference r-value and allow the move as soon as the `std::move` is applied explicitly. I understand that `std::move` is simply a static cast so that implementing a "custom" `move` is not a real option here (like, e.g., having a custom `swap`).

Any ideas or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: you shouldn't care about move or not. if the user overloaded the copy and the move constructor - the compiler is smart enough to decide which one to call

Comment: I write the (move) constructor and I need to be smart enough to distinguish between doing moves or copies. Relying on the compiler does not give what I need in this case.

Comment: Ah: `* iterator` returns a pseudo-ref by-value.  Then `std::move` ... does nothing of interest (is not detectable).  Storing the pseudo-reference in the iterator is a non-starter (as destruction/reuse of the iterator makes the pseudo-reference unusable), so there really isn't a good spot to store the psudo-reference in order for `*` to return a reference to it (and then you'd be able to detect `std::move`).  Temporaries created in your code do not persist into the caller, and you cannot move the operation of construction of another type into your code.  Hurm.  Good question.

Comment: [Eric](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) is implementing a ranges library for `std` that attempts to normalize pseudo-references.  Wonder how he solved it?

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for the comment! I saw already a reference to range in one related question here on SO. The library however implements its own set of algorithms so I'm not sure he needs to care about this kind of problem.

Comment: Oh, something that doesn't work: `struct foo { operator foo&&()&; }`.

Comment: @Yakk Yep. No matter whether `foo` is passed to move as r-value or l-value reference.

Comment: `reference_wrapper` [has a `get` function (and a `&` operator)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get), which returns an lvalue-reference to the original object. Applying `std::move` to the result of that [does net you a moved-from object](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d5d2672dcb2cd42), as one would expect. Perhaps you could do something similar? Of course, this complicates the syntax on the part of the caller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an overload `move` for `wrapperType`.

```
namespace std
{
    SomeType move(my_namespace::wrapperType&) {/* Your implementation */}
}
```

Care to include it each time `std::move` can be called, else, program is ill-formed without required diagnostic.

`std::forward` may have similar treatment.

Note: Declare/define function/class in `std` is most of the time UB.

Comment: Interesting. I assumed `std::move` was *required* to act as a cast to an r-value, but it's just required to indicate that the object can be moved from, not necessarily in the form of an r-value cast?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I though about this too but it seemed wicked for me to touch `std`. It works in some cases, e.g., may give me some improvements for the GCC's implementation of insertion sort. However, not in all cases, e.g., the `std::move` algorithm ignores my overload completely and the implementation makes copies.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: You have to care to have better match than standard `std::move` as `move(const wrapper&)` is not an exact match over `move(T&&)` for `wrapper&`.